# Why does LogonUserW fail with error code 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, authentication

I checked the error code by calling GetLastError() right after the failure of LogonUserW, it is always 183, but I don't know why does LogonUserW fail with such a value. Searched the msdn, and found 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) means "Cannot create a file when that file already exists", so what file will LogonUserW create?

Can anyone shed some light here please?

```
if (LogonUserW(uniUserName, uniDomainName, uniPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token))
{
//do something when success
}
else
{
    STI_LOG(LOG_AUTH_DETAILS, ("Login fail\n"), true);
    DWORD ec = GetLastError();
    String message;
    switch (ec)
    {
        case ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD:
            message = "Error Privilege not held\n";
            break;
        case ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE:
            message = "Error Logon Failure\n";
            break;
        //...
        default:
            message = "Other errors\n";
    }
    STI_LOG(LOG_ERROR, ("Fail to log in user: %d-%s\n", ec, message.getCString()), true);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: I added the piece of code above, it is quite simple.

Comment: Maybe returned token is still in use. (I dont see CloseHandle)

Answer (score 5):

Before you call `GetLastError`, you are executing some logging code in this macro:

```
STI_LOG(LOG_AUTH_DETAILS, ("Login fail\n"), true);
```

It's quite possible that one of the API calls in this logging function is also setting the last error flag. Certainly an error like "file already exists" is much more consistent with a logging function than with a logon.

So, first of all you should call `GetLastError` *immediately* after the failing function call:

```
if (LogonUserW(uniUserName, uniDomainName, 
        uniPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token))
{
    //do something when success
}
else
{
    DWORD ec = GetLastError();

    STI_LOG(LOG_AUTH_DETAILS, ("Login fail\n"), true);

    // ... etc. ...
}
```

As it [says on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

[image: msdn]

After you make this change, see if the return code from `GetLastError` is more like what you expected.